# python works in cmd, but not in bash

Tags: python, windows, bash, cmd, mingw

I have a python script that I would like to run while in the MinGW bash environment (inside a bash script)

I have python 3.5 installed and in the PATH.

This is basically what happens when I try to start python in cmd, and then in bash.

```
C:\Users\mkhoory-test>python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

C:\Users\mkhoory-test>bash
bash-3.1$ python
 - Cannot openbash-3.1$
```

I'm stumped. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Try to set 'PATH' to point to your installed Python

Comment: Firstly, try to use the absolute path to your Python executable. If it works, then there is something wrong with your `PATH` variable.

Comment: This is strange.. python was already in the path. However, I seem to have 2 locations for python.. Check my comment in Christian's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` file, which should be located under `C:\Users\[Username]\` you can add an entry for your **PATH**. If the file is not there, you can add it.

```
PATH=/c/PathToPythonInstallation
```

If you have multiple directories to add, use `:` to delimit each entry, unlike the Windows norm of `;`.

If you set it in the `.bashrc` you'll need to either close and re-open the bash shell, or type `source ~/.bashrc` to load it up.

You can also temporarily set the path for the lifetime of your shell session by using **export** like `export PATH=/c/PathToPythonInstallation`.

Comment: You're right, but here's where it gets strange... python was already in the path! Keep in mind that bash uses the path set by Windows already, so anything executable by cmd should be executable by bash from the start. After some inspection there seems to be one python.exe in system32, which is what bash was trying to execute, and there was also one in my AppData folder somewhere. The system32 one doesn't seem to work, but the one in AppData worked. Setting the path so that the AppData folder is searched first makes python work. I cannot explain it however... why doesn't the system32 one work?

Comment: After some more digging, python.exe actually isn't in system32 (I can't find it in the folder if I look manually).... but the command `where python` says it is, and lists the system32 location as the first location. I can't explain this. Also, alternatively, I can use "py" instead of "python" and it works without needing to set the PATH..

Comment: Another thing to note: if python truly wasn't in the PATH, I would've gotten a "command not found" error. But I'm getting a "cannot open" error, which is different.